# SQL Server very fast in local network and extremely slow when accessing over Internet

Tags: sql

What I did, for a test, since my database that I work on is very slow when accessing over the Internet, is:

- I've installed SQL Server 2014 with latest MSSMS
- I've opened a port on a router and I've added a rule to Firewall. Also, I enabled access for an IP address in Configuration Manager. I see database from Internet
- I've made only one table with 5 records, let's call it tblEmployees with index field
- I am running it on my home computer where nothing is using the Internet. There is 35 Mbps down and 3 Mbps up connection. Technically free of traffic
- Distance from the place I try the remote connection to my home PC is really short, less than 100 miles. Tracert, ping is fine

Now, when I run SELECT TOP 5 FROM tblEmployees in MSSMS on my home network, I get data immediately, but when I do the same remotely using MSSMS (or program I am working on, it is the same), I get data in about 6 seconds. It is even worse for "bigger" sets of data, where that "bigger" is, for example, the list of 300 clients. That is like few kB of data, but I need to wait more than 10 seconds just to open a table.

I am reading about this perhaps whole last week. AUTO_CLOSE is set to OFF.

At the same time I am running MySQL server on the same PC, also with Internet access. It works fast. But SQL Server works really slow. That means the issue is related with some settings of SQL Server... but which one?

Comment: In addition to shodanshok's answer, [this article](https://scrutin.wordpress.com/2007/04/30/elephants-on-the-network-lfns-long-fat-networks-bandwidth-versus-latency/) might help.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard: IMO, the `Big Three` factors that affect network performance are bandwidth (capacity), latency (delay) and packet loss. Too often people focus on bandwidth and give no thought to latency and packet loss. "My internet connection is slow but I have a 10Mbps connection!" is too often heard without any consideration of the other two factors. Thanks for posting that link in your comment.

Comment: Too bad that people often read just half the lines. You stopped probably at 1/3 of my post - if you did not you'll see I am describing ping, tracert and that the MySQL is not working slow on the SAME LINE.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your workload is very sensitive to network latency (albeit a simple SELECT should not show that behavior).

To debug further, I need the network dump of a SELECT statement. Please do the following:

1. install wireshark to your Windows PC
2. connect to your database using SSL (to prevent any private information to leak into the packet dump)
3. start sniffing packets
4. execute a SELECT statement
5. stop sniffing
6. cancel out any sensitive information remaining
7. show here the dump